# cs50 week 9 finance. I get the error that loggining in as registered user does not succeed

Tags: cs50

when i ruck check50 i get the error
when i log in as a registered account I also do not get any errors

```
:( logging in as registered user succceeds
Cause
expected status code 200, but got 400
Log
sending POST request to /login
checking that status code 200 is returned...
```

however when i use the program myself the logging in as a registered user works fine

this is my register code from application.py

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""
    if (request.method == "POST"):

        username=request.form.get('username') 
        password=request.form.get('password') 
        confirmation=request.form.get('confirmation') 
        
        if not username: #if there is no username
            return apology('enter a username')
        elif not password: #if there is no password
            return apology('enter a password')
        elif not confirmation: #if there is no confirmation
            return apology('Password confirmation is required!')
            
        if password !=confirmation: #if password is not equal to confirmation
            return apology("Password does not match")
        
        hash = generate_password_hash(password)
        try:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username,hash) VALUES (?, ?)", username, hash)
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return apology("Username has allready been registered")
    else:
        return render_template("register.html") #display the page if no errors
```

this is also my template register.html code for the code above

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div> 
        
        
        
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        </div>
        
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
        </div>
        
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to have the index.html (the table) made for that check50 to mark is correct

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer, but you can try this workaround.

Instead of using try and except blocks, get the rows from the database having username as the username entered by user. Then check if there are no rows. If there are no rows then you can assume the username is unique and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I am late but this answer is for those who are also facing similar issue.
In my case the issue was in index page it happens when you login for the first time there is nothing to show so for that I had returned apology saying "you don't have any stocks" and apology was sending 400 error code so I just removed that code and the problem solved.
this line is simply telling that when a new user login you app is showing 400 error.